# .Net Core Razor pages using EF Core CRUD edit model exclude non nullable fields without causing error

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, ef-core-2.1

I am using .net core 2.1 razor pages.  I have CRUD pages where I only show some fields from my model.  The fields that I do not show get default values provided to the create model.

I'm having an issue with my edit models.  My setup is that I only want to be able to edit certain fields on my model.  When I do not include fields that are mapped to non nullable fields in my database, I get an error even though those fields were already populated when the record was created.

How do I handle this?  Do I have to customize the edit model to specify what fields I want to bind to my edit form? Pointers to documentation or samples would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you attaching the entity object as modified?  If so, it will mark all properties as modified.  Use the `EntityEntry` to set the `IsModified` property for the relevant properties to `false` so that EF will not attempt to update their values in the store.

```
// gets EntityEntry and begins tracking if not currently tracked
var entry = dbContext.Entry( yourEntity );
// set as modified
entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
// for each property you don't want updated in store:
entry.Property( e => e.PropertyName )
    .IsModified = false;
```

Comment: The default scaffolded pages have the following entry: `_context.Attach(MyModel).State = EntityState.Modified;` which I think is what you are referring to.  II'm guessing I would do the following:  `_context.Attach(MyModel).Property(e => e.MyModelPropId).IsModified = false;`

Comment: Where can I find documentation/samples/books for this?  I've searched quite a bit and didn't come up with anything.

Comment: start By googling “entity framework core change tracking” and reading the resulting Microsoft docs and assorted tutorials

Answer (score 3):

As a tip , it is not a good idea to use domain models directly in view pages , a better way is creating viewModel class for view pages and then mapping them to domain classes before adding them to dbcontext..
read more about AutoMapper tool and viewModels in mvc